# I am using react datepicker in multistep form i want after selecting date and press continue and move next , when i come back step don't get date

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using React date picker in a multistep form when I choose date and press continue back and then go to previous step I won't get date picker value I using redux and get data from redux , setValue using it. I am also use react hook form.  Please guide me how can i get date picker value when I click on previous step?

```js
<DatePicker
  id="start_ds"
  placeholderText="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
  selected={startDates}
  //value={startDates}
  onChange={(date) => setStartDates(date ? date : "")}
  showTimeSelect
  minDate={new Date()} //set the current date to disable past
  date
  minTime={new Date().getTime()} //set current time to disable past time
  maxTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 59), 23)} //this set the max time (i.e. 23:59)
  dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
  required={true}
  name="start_date"
  autoComplete="off"
/>

const oldData = useSelector((props) => props.events);

if ($("#start_ds").val() === undefined) {
  setValue("start_date", oldData.selectedDates.start_date);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more info like working codesandbox of the issue.